# Как запретить методы определенному пользователю в resourse rout?

Tags: laravel, resources, middleware

Есть 4 роли (**admin, manager, master, user**). Есть
`Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');`
Как мне запретить например master методы ('index','show') использовать, а user ('destroy'). Я так понимаю, что нужен 1 общий middleware который будет этим процессом управлять. Но я не пойму какое условие делать.
 Пытался так: но не вышло

```html
 if(!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->role->role === 'admin') {
            $this->middleware('profile', ['except' => ['show']]);
            return $next($request);
        } elseif (Auth::user()->role->role === 'manager') {
            $this->middleware('profile', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
            return $next($request);
        } 
        ............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать при помощи политик Laravel.

Создаете политику, в ней проверяете права доступа к конкретному действию.

Подробнее об этом - ***[https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/authorization#генерирование](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/authorization#%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)***

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться с политикой.